# PHP: send data from internet to local script

Tags: php, curl, localhost

Can I send data from internet php script to a local php script on my local server?

Comment: If your local server is part of the internet, i.e. if you have an IP address that you can send the information to and if your firewall etc. allow a connection from outside.

Comment: too little information. You could use something like cURL to execute that "internet PHP script" and get result from it on your local script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if only your local server is somehow accessible from outside.